# C# Beginner problems

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have a "Debug" class, which simply prints information to the console etc. From the rest of the code I want to be able to call the methods within it, but so far it's only partly working.

Calling `dc.Print()` works fine, but as soon as I call `dc.Print(dc.GetEventsLogged())` I get a red line with the message

***"The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments"*** as well as Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'.

Basically: Why are my arguments to dc.Print wrong? Also, what can I do about "cannot convert from int to string? I tried .ToString but that didn't work either.

This is my "Debug.cs" class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Test
{
    public class Debug
    {
        private int events_logged;

        public Debug()
        {
            events_logged = 0;
        }

        public void Print(string Message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.UtcNow + "] " + Message);
            events_logged++;
        }


        public int GetEventsLogged()
        {
        return events_logged;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my "Program.cs" class I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debug dc = new Debug();
            dc.Print("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the error is because `GetEventsLogged()` returns an `int` whereas `Print()` expects you to pass in a `string`. Therefore you need to the return from `int` to `string` and you were on the right track with `ToString()`. This will do what you want to achieve:

```
dc.Print(dc.GetEventsLogged().ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine :) I was trying .ToString without a ()

Comment: No problem and welcome to StackOverflow! You will find lots of helpful people here and we all have to start somewhere! Could you please click the TICK next to this answer to mark it as "Solved" which will help other people find this question if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

`dc.Print()` wants a string argument and `dc.GetEventsLogged()` returns an `int`. You need to `ToString()` the `int` so that the types match.

```
int numberOfEventsLogged = dc.GetEventsLogged();

string numberOfEventsLoggedAsString = numberOfEventsLogged.ToString();

dc.Print(numberOfEventsLoggedAsString)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `dc.Print(dc.GetEventsLogged().toString())` because `GetEventsLogged()` is of int type and `Print(string Message)` looking for string input.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `Print` expects an argument of type `String`. When you call `dc.Print(dc.GetEventsLogged())`, your actually give an `int` because your method   `GetEventsLogged()` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string GetEventsLogged()
    {
        return events_logged.ToString();
    }
```